# Crossing an altitude in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Python script that calculates the trajectory of an object from the ground up above 100,000-meters then back below 100,000-meters. I want to be able to figure out how much time is spent above 100,000-meters. I have my trajectory code just fine (Runge-Kutta), and I can get up to 100,000-meters. However, I cannot figure out the right Python algorithm to keep going up to max altitude and start coming down to below 100,000-meters.

Here is what I have:

`while (states[4,(i - 1)] >= 100000 and states[4,i] <= 100000 or states[4,i] != 100000):`

I'm ending up in an infinite loop, though. `states[4,i]` is the altitude. My thinking is that if the previous (`i - 1`) altitude is above 100,000-meters and the current (`i`) altitude is below 100,000-meters, I want it to exit the while loop. `states[4,i] != 100000` is meant to get me up to that altitude, at least.

Thoughts?

Comment: "`states[4,i] != 100000` is meant to get me up to that altitude" ... How so? `!=` is the not-equal comparison operator, not the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you have here is that you need to keep track of when you cross the altitude. Why not just have a variable set to false before your loop, then true when you hit >= 100000, and add that to your while. Also, those conditionals are for leaving your loop, so you should negate it. E.g.

```
reachedHeight = False
while (not (reachedHeight and states[4,(i - 1)] >= 100000 and states[4,i] <= 100000)):
  if (not reachedHeight and states[4,i] >= 100000):
    reachedHeight = True
  ...
```

Could also be a conditional with a break inside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop you have above will continue looping unless `states[4,i]` equals **exactly** 100,000.

`False and False or True == True`

This is likely why you are experiencing the infinite loop. You may want to remove the third case and if necessary, perform other checks inside the loop.